# Matlab element-wise power - can't understand how it works

Tags: matlab, plot, elementwise-operations

I have a matched filter, which I want to plot its frequency response in Matlab.

The filter response is: H(f) = [image: Frequency response of wiener filter]

I tried to to plot it with:

```
%Freqency_Response_of_wiener_filter
f = linspace(-1e3,1e3,1e5);
H = ((2*pi*f)^2+10^6)/(11*(2*pi*f)^2+10^6+10^4);
plot(f,H);
xlabel('f')
ylabel('H(f)')
```

which not working, giving me error of 'Matrix dimensions must agree' kind.
I then read about 'element-wise power', which seems to fit exactly to what I need, and changed `H` to:

```
H = ((2*pi*f).^2+10^6)/(11*(2*pi*f).^2+10^6+10^4);
```

This indeed plot something, just not what I want :)
I tried also

```
H = ((2*pi)^2*f.^2+10^6)/(11*(2*pi)^2*f.^2+10^6+10^4);
```

with no luck.
The only way I got it working is:

```
%Freqency_Response_of_wiener_filter
f = linspace(-1e3,1e3,1e5);
for i=1:length(f)
  H(i) = ((2*pi*f(i))^2+10^6)/(11*(2*pi*f(i))^2+10^6+10^4);
end
plot(f,H);
```

Why is 'element-wise power' not working for me?

More than that - what exactly the differenece between regular operation to 'element-wise operation'? Because, for example, over here: [An Introduction to Matlab](http://web.uvic.ca/~monahana/eos225/matlab_tutorial/tutorial_1/introduction_to_matlab.html), there's this plot:

```
a = 0:.01:5;
b = cos(2*pi*a);
plot(a,b)
```

and then this one:

```
x = 2:.1:4;
y = 1./x;
plot(x,y)
xlabel('x');
ylabel('y');
```

and I can't tell any difference between them. Why on the first one there was no need of 'element-wise operation', while in the second one there was?

Thanks.

Comment: Simple rule of thumb: when you want to do element wise operations: chuck in a dot before every `/`, `*` and `^`. It's a bit overkill, i.e. `2.*pi` is not doing anything else than `2*pi` since both are already scalars, but at least it'd save you from debugging these kind of hard-to-find errors.

Comment: I second Adriaan's comment. You don't need it to multiply a scalar by a matrix, but if you have two matrices (`x,y`) with a scalar (`k`) in between you might get into debugging problems: `x*k` and `k*y` both work, but `x*k*y` will cause an error. Instead of figuring out where to put the dot/dots, simply put it both places: `x.*k.*y`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why `H = ((2*pi)^2*f.^2+10^6)/(11*(2*pi)^2*f.^2+10^6+10^4);` did not work is because you need `./`:

```
H = ((2*pi)^2*f.^2+10^6)./(11*(2*pi)^2*f.^2+10^6+10^4);
```

In the first case:

```
a = 0:.01:5;
b = cos(2*pi*a);
plot(a,b)
```

you do not need an element-wise-operation because there is only one way of doing the cosine of a vector or a matrix.

On the other hand, in another case:

```
x = 2:.1:4;
y = x.^2;
plot(x,y)
xlabel('x');
ylabel('y');
```

You need to specify that you want to make the element-wise operation rather than multiplying the matrix by itself (that works only for square matrices).

In the second case you post:

```
x = 2:.1:4;
y = 1./x;
plot(x,y)
xlabel('x');
ylabel('y');
```

you need the `.` so that Matlab understand that `1` has to be a vector of ones with length `numel(x)`.